# Can mysql properly display all characters in utf8?

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

Maximum number of bytes for a UTF-8 in mysql is 3.

```
show character set like 'utf8';
+---------+---------------+-------------------+--------+
| Charset | Description   | Default collation | Maxlen |
+---------+---------------+-------------------+--------+
| utf8    | UTF-8 Unicode | utf8_general_ci   |      3 |
+---------+---------------+-------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In the wiki
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#cite_note-2

UTF-8 is a character encoding capable of encoding all 1,112,064[1] valid code points in Unicode using one to four 8-bit bytes.

Does it mean that not all characters in utf8 can be displayed properly,or say ,
some characters encoding with 4 bytes in utf8 can
not be displayed in mysql properly?
Can mysql properly display all characters in utf8?

Comment: It can’t; you need to use utf8mb4.

Comment: MySQL doesn't *display* anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have `utf8mb4` collation it will simply delete characters "too big" to fit. `utf8` is, in MySQL, "up to three bytes".